# Can you use は twice in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

Can you say 'アンナさんの性格は明るくなくて、少しつめたいので、新しい友達ができるのは難しいです。’ or does it sound a little awkward? Can you use は twice here in a sentence? What I'm trying to say here is that because Anna does not have a bright personality & come across as a standoffish person, it's hard for her to make new friends.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, **make** new friends = 新しい友達を**作る**. If you say about someone that 新しい友達ができるのは難しい, it sort of sounds like "it's unlikely they'll find anyone willing to be their friend", which as a verdict is of course a lot harsher...

Answer (score 1):

Unlike が and を there is nothing wrong with は twice or even thrice. eg. (someone edit in a better one...)

今日は私は子供は送らない。